# How to send HTTP request via proxy server using javascript in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

I need to send ajax request from a web page using javascript via proxy server.

Example, the web-page will fetch data from https://microsoft.com using ajax while routing the request through proxy server say `52.19.199.210`

Is there a way to do this?

**Update**

I think I was not clear. The request needs to go via proxy server and the destination is dynamic. That is JavaScript will request for https://microsoft.com or https://google.com or any other URL and all these requests need to go through the proxy server

And I cannot use browser proxy because its the requirement of the webpage not users

Comment: Ajax makes request to proxy script. Proxy script (written in whatever language your server supports) requests data from other server and returns it to ajax request. Is done all the time. Do a search on how to make remote server request using whatever language your server supports

Comment: `123.234.345.456` is an invalid IP address, so, no, you can't do that - but seriously, yes of course you can do that

Comment: are you using node.js?

Comment: No plain javascript in web browser